# Two images aligned to the center of the page

Tags: beamer, graphics, horizontal-alignment

I need to add two logos on the first slide. The problem is that these logos have very different dimensions. So I have decided to align to the centre of the page.

The slide should look like this:

```
|                                |
|                                |
|         TITLE AND STUFF        |
|             AUTHORS            |
|                                |
|      | logo 1 ||  logo 2      ||
|      |        ||              ||
|      |        |                |
|      |        |                |
|                                |
```

How can I achieve this layout in beamer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a `beamer` solution for `\maketitle`. It puts both logos into `\titlegraphic`, aligned at the middle. I used an asterisk for the date to verify the center adjustment.

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\title{Presentation Title}
\author{Author}
\date{*}
\titlegraphic{%
  \mbox{}%
  \llap{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{logo1}\quad}%
  \rlap{\quad\includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo2}}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

- `\llap` and `\rlap` hide the real width of the images.
- `\raisebox{-\height}{...}` shifts their baseline to the top for top alignment.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it. First go inside a center environment then place the left graphic in a zero width box "facing" left and the right graphic in a zero width box facing right. E.g.,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]

\begin{center}
  \makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \fbox{\rule{10em}{20em}}% = first graphic
  }%
  \qquad % space in the middle
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \fbox{\rule{20em}{10em}}% = second graphic
  }%
\end{center}

\lipsum[14]
\end{document}
```

(Note this isn't specific to beamer but will work equally well there.)